# Xmpp gtalk authentication with google access token

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp, google-talk

I am using xmpp framework to integrate gtalk in my application. I have successfully authenticated user using OAuth 2.0. Now i want to use the access token and user email to authenticate xmpp stream. I know that the authentication call get sent xmppStreamDidConnect method using this method authenticateWithPassword. This requires a password, i want to get it done using the google access token. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it please follow the steps:

1. Register your app on google developer  console.
2. Generate access token with following scope:
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googletalk
3. start authentication as following:

   - (BOOL)start:(NSError **)errPtr
     {
     XMPPLogTrace();

   // From RFC 4616 - PLAIN SASL Mechanism:
   // [authzid] UTF8NUL authcid UTF8NUL passwd
   // 
   // authzid: authorization identity
   // authcid: authentication identity (username)
   // passwd : password for authcid

NSString *accessToken = @"ACCESS-TOKEN-STRING-FROM Google";//TODO: assign your generated access token
    NSLog(@"stream supports: %@",xmppStream.supportedAuthenticationMechanisms);
   NSString *payload = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\0%@\0%@", xmppStream.hostName, accessToken];
    NSLog(@"payload = %@",payload);
  NSString  *base64 = [[payload dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] xmpp_base64Encoded];
    NSXMLElement *auth = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"auth" xmlns:@"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"];
    [auth addAttributeWithName:@"mechanism" stringValue:@"X-OAUTH2"];
    [auth addAttributeWithName:@"auth:service" stringValue:@"oauth2"];
    [auth addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns:auth" stringValue:@"https://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth"];
    [auth setStringValue:base64];

```
[xmppStream sendAuthElement:auth];

return YES;
```

}

Everything should work as expected, please comment.